# How to disable Insecure Password Warning in Firefox using Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am new to Selenium Webdriver. I am trying to test my application login page in Firefox. Every time while doing so I am getting insecure password warning (This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised).

This is coming when password is entered. How to disable that in selenium Webdriver using Java?

Currently I am using this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPathFF); 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true); 
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true); 
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

But it is not helping. I tried other ways found in related google search as well but no luck.

Please check the link for reference.
   [Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN4yc.png)

Comment: Please ensure that are using the latest Firefox.

Comment: I am using FF 53.0.3

Comment: @Payel IMO you are messing up 2 points here `insecure password warning` and `connection is not secure`. Can you consider updating us with your exact manual steps and the URL? Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I guess so. Actually I searched for the insecure password warning only and tried all the possible solution found, but nothing did work . Hence I am here....What I am trying to do is to automate the login page (screenshot attached above). After entering password, I am getting the above warning, hiding the login button. So my test case is getting failed, instead of clicking on Login Button it is clicking on Learn More of the warning. I want some way in selenium so that this password warning does not come up with FF window. My script is running properly in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to set preferences for firefox using Selenium.
For example,

```
var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("security.insecure_password.ui.enabled", false);
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);
```

It represents values that can be changed manually by opening Firefox, typing about:config and finding the same options.
It helped my tests to avoid the insecure login message.

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating firefox profile like the below one,

```
profile = new FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver(dc);
```

Comment: Thank You...But it did not work...still that warning is coming whenever password is entered.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript way of doing this:

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

    var profile = new firefox.Profile();
    profile.setPreference("security.insecure_password.ui.enabled", false);
    profile.setPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);

    var options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);
    var browserUnderTest = new webdriver.Builder()   
     .forBrowser('firefox')
     .setFirefoxOptions(options)
     .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If am right, I think there's a way to achieve that using selenium:
Something of this nature;

```
var firefox = new FirefoxOptions();
firefox.SetPreference("security.insecure_password.ui.enabled", false);
```

Not too sure about that though! But just give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

In Java this worked for me

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);
```